# Weird behavior when rotating an element on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Given these two examples.

## Using Hover

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--deg));
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  --deg: 180deg;
  --top: 20%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  --deg: -180deg;
  --top: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  --deg: 360deg;
  --top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>180deg</div>
<div>-180deg</div>
<div>360deg</div>
```

---

## Using Animation

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  animation: rotate 2s linear 2s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--deg));
  }
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  --deg: 180deg;
  --top: 20%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  --deg: -180deg;
  --top: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  --deg: 360deg;
  --top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>180deg</div>
<div>-180deg</div>
<div>360deg</div>
```

---

As you can see `rotate(180deg)` and `rotate(-180deg)` act the same and `rotate(360deg)` doesn't move at all.

The problem is if you would have it move gradually it acts normally.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

div:hover {
  animation: rotate 2s linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The solution that i found is to replace `translate(-50%, -50%)` with `margins` which is not consistent

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  transition: transform 2s;
  /* Minus half the width, hard coded not a good idea*/
  margin: 0 0 0 -75px; 
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

div:hover {
  transform: rotate(var(--deg));
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  --deg: 180deg;
  --top: 20%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  --deg: -180deg;
  --top: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  --deg: 360deg;
  --top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>180deg</div>
<div>-180deg</div>
<div>360deg</div>
```

So The main question is Why that weird behavior is taking place ?

**EDIT : Not looking for just a quick answer (as you can see there's two available) but an explanation as well :)**

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2021: The bug no more occur**

It seems a browser bug (at least on Chrome) as it works fine if your try the code on Firefox.

Let refer to the  [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#interpolation-of-transforms) to explain this. Here is all the different cases of how interpolation between transform should work.

[image]

In our case, we will consider the last point where we don't have the same number of transform functions and the browser should handle this by adding the identity transform function from the missing list and in our case it should be `rotate(0)`.

So technically a transition from `translate(-50%)` to `translate(-50%) rotate(360deg)` should be the same as a transition from `translate(-50%) rotate(0)` to `translate(-50%) rotate(360deg)`.

Unless, I am missing something this is for sure a bug as in the case when `rotate(360deg)` is used alone, Chrome is handling this fine using the second point (when one value is `none`) which is almost the same as the last point.

Comment: I see so, it's just chrome not following the spec, i suppose we mustn't relay on browser's to clean after us, Thank you :)

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa or you can report this as a bug to the chrome team ;) it may get fixed because it's a very particular case

Comment: i will certainly look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an initial `rotate(0)`, so there can be animation between the two states. Set the `div`'s initial transform to:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
```

**Transition:**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--deg));
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  --deg: 180deg;
  --top: 20%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  --deg: -180deg;
  --top: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  --deg: 360deg;
  --top: 60%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>180deg</div>
<div>-180deg</div>
<div>360deg</div>
```

**Animation:**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  left: 50%;
  top: var(--top);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  animation: rotate 2s linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(var(--deg));
  }
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  --deg: 180deg;
  --top: 20%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  --deg: -180deg;
  --top: 40%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  --deg: 360deg;
  --top: 60%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>180deg</div>
<div>-180deg</div>
<div>360deg</div>
```

Comment: If i use margins to position the divs, `rotate(0)` is not needed, Why ?

Comment: I can only guess that when transform is not initialised at all, the change is detected correctly.

Comment: Yes exactly i would like to understand why is that.